# ArcPy QueryPointAndDistance: Incorrect Lengths?

Tags: python, arcpy

Background:

I'm currently trying to determine the chainage (distance m) of points
along a polyline (i.e. proposed railway alignment). A colleague within my firm
assisted me writing the following script.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Some\Arb\Folder\work.gdb"

# Input variables
fc_line = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer("ftr_line")
fc_pnt = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer("ftr_point")

# Get line geometry - assumes only one feature in feature class
polyline = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_line, "SHAPE@").next()[0]

# Loop over the point feature class
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_pnt, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Get the percentage the current point is along the line
        perc = polyline.queryPointAndDistance(row[0], True)[1]
        # Calculate the percentage distance in metres
        dist = polyline.getLength()*perc
        print("% along line: {0}%\tDistance along line: {1}m".format(round(perc*100, 2), round(dist, 2)))

print("Script complete.")
```

Comparison:

I compared the values generated by the following script and
splitting the polyline manually based on the point positions. The values differ by approximately by 4m.

[image]

The following is the first position along the line and the value
determined by the script is 871 and the value determined manually is 875.

[image]

If anyone can give me advise in how to resolve the following, it
will truly be appreciated.

Comment: If your data does not have a defined coordinate system, you will get geometry errors.